# I want to find some string in front of another string pattern, how to do it?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I want to use bash shell to split string like:

```
Calcipotriol - Daivonex Cream 50mcg/1g 30 g [1]
Aspirin - DBL Aspirin 100mg [1] tablet
```

I want to get brand name "Davionex Cream" and "DBL Aspirin"
I want to get the name in front of parttern ***mg or ***mcg or ***g

how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bash you can do:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:][:punct:]]+([[:alpha:][:space:]]+)[[:space:]](.*)$ ]]
    then
         printf "1:'%s' 2:'%s' 3:'%s'\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    fi  
    done <<<"Calcipotriol - Daivonex Cream 50mcg/1g 30 g [1]
Aspirin - DBL Aspirin 100mg [1] tablet"
```

Prints:

```
1:'Calcipotriol' 2:'Daivonex Cream' 3:'50mcg/1g 30 g [1]'
1:'Aspirin' 2:'DBL Aspirin' 3:'100mg [1] tablet'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your sample input is representative, `awk` may offer the simplest solution:

```
awk -F'- | [0-9]+(mc?)?g' '{ print $2 }' <<'EOF'
Calcipotriol - Daivonex Cream 50mcg/1g 30 g [1]
Aspirin - DBL Aspirin 100mg [1] tablet
Foo - Foo Bar 22g [1] other
EOF
```

yields:

```
Daivonex Cream
DBL Aspirin
Foo Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` this way:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:alpha:]]+ - ([[:alpha:] ]+) [[:digit:]]+.*/\1/' <<< "Calcipotriol - Daivonex Cream 50mcg/1g 30 g [1]"

=> Daivonex Cream
```

- `^[[:alpha:]]+ -` => matches all the characters until the pattern we need to extract
- `([[:alpha:] ]+)`  => this is the part we want to extract
- `[[:digit:]]+.*`  => this is everything that comes after; we assume this part starts with a space and one or more digits, followed by any number of characters
- `\1`               => the part extracted by the `(...)` expression above; 
                      we replace the entire string with the matched part

---

You can check out this site to learn more about regexes: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Can you tell me what the last characters ".*/\1/ " that meaning

Comment: It places the first pattern matched through '(...)` expression.  We have only one such match in the expression used here.

Comment: Just added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: I want use similar regrex to get 50mcg/1g  30 g but get wrong feedback. Do you know why?    sed -E 's/^[[:alpha:] ]+ ([[:digit:]]+[mcg | mg | g]+) \\[.*/\1/' <<< "Daivonex Cream 50mc
g/1g 30 g [1]"