# Regex with capture groups for substrings made up of a variable number of words

Tags: regex, linux, bash, capture-group

With the following Bash script (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059231/45375)):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
if [[ "$line" =~ ^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:][:punct:]]+([[:alpha:][:space:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:digit:]+[mcg|mg|g][:space:][\/0-9a-zA-Z[：space：]]*])[\[]([[:digit:]]+)[\]]([[:alpha:]]*)$ ]]
then
 printf "Ingredient: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
 printf "Brand name: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
 printf "Strength: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
 printf "Pack size: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
 printf "Form: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
fi  
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

I want to match lines such as the following (provided via stdin or via a file passed as the first argument):

```
Calcipotriol - Daivonex Cream 50mcg/1g 30 g [1]
Candesartan cilexetil - Atacand 4mg [30] capsule
Danazol - Azol 100mg [100] 
Dexamethasone - Dexmethsone 0.5g [1] tablet
```

and parse them into 4-5 fields.

For instance, line `Calcipotriol - Daivonex Cream 50mcg/1g 30 g [1]` should be broken into fields as follows:

- `Calcipotriol` (ingredient)
- `Daivonex Cream` (brand name)
- `50mcg/1g 30 g` (strength)
- `1` (pack size)
- (empty, because no text follows `[1]`) (form)

However, when I run my script, *nothing* matches.

Here is the regex in isolation (line breaks are just for readability):
`^([[:alpha:]]+)[[:space:][:punct:]]+([[:alpha:][:space:]]+)[[:space:]]([[:digit:]+[mcg|mg|g][:space:][\/0-9a-zA-Z[：space：]]*])[\[]([[:digit:]]+)[\]]([[:alpha:]]*)$`

Can you tell me how to match a string such as `50mcg/1g 30 g` and capture it in  `${BASH_REMATCH[4]}`?

Comment: Your inputs are not consistent.

Comment: @heemayl where my inputs not consistent

Comment: IIUC, in the first two, i see 5 extractable fields, whereas in the last two i see 4. Make your output specific.

Comment: @heemay1 the 5 extractable field is: ([[:alpha:]]+),([[:alpha:][:space:]]+), ([[:digit:]+[mcg|mg|g]+[\/0-9a-zA-Z[:space:]]*]),([[:digit:]]) and ([[:alpha:]]*) the last one can be empty

Comment: @heemayl can you help me to check the 3rd extractable, I am not sure for that

Comment: In the last occurrence of `[:space:]`, you have something weird going on with your colons (they are ["fullwidtdh colons"](https://unicode-table.com/en/FF1A/)). Also, `[mcg|mg|g]` is not "`mcg` or `mg` or `g`", it's a bracket expression (`m` or `c` or `g` or `|`). What you probably meant is `(mcg|mg|g)`, which can be written `(mc?)?g`.

Comment: @user504909: Please add the _expected output_ for your sample input to your question.

Comment: @user504909: My fixed version of your `bash` solution should now work correctly, but how hard it was to get it right again suggests an `awk` solution may be better. I've also added a (partial) analysis of why your solution didn't work, as well as tips for visualizing and debugging regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was the case with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42058416/45375), **`awk` offers a more maintainable - and much faster - solution**:

`awk` is the best choice, because **your input is essentially *field*-based**, and breaking input into fields is where `awk` shines. To learn about `awk`, see the [`awk` POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) or run `man awk` or `info awk` on your system.

<sup>For simplicity, and in line with the sample input, all intra-line whitespace is assumed to be *spaces*; replace the  instances in the regexes with `[[:blank:]]` if tabs should be matched too.</sup>

```
awk -F' +- +|[][]' '
  { 
    name = $2; sub(" +[0-9.]+(mc?)?g.*", "", name)
    strength = substr($2, 1 + length(name)); sub("^ +", "", strength)
    form = ""
    if (NF > 3) { form = $NF; sub("^ +", "", form) }

    print "Ingredient:", $1
    print "Brand name:", name
    print "Strength:  ", strength
    print "Pack size: ", $3
    print "Form:      ", form
    print "---"
  }
' <<'EOF'
Calcipotriol - Daivonex Cream 50mcg/1g 30 g [1]
Candesartan cilexetil - Atacand 4mg [30] capsule
Danazol - Azol 100mg [100] 
Dexamethasone - Dexmethsone 0.5g [1] tablet
EOF
```

yields:

```
Ingredient: Calcipotriol
Brand name: Daivonex Cream
Strength:   50mcg/1g 30 g 
Pack size:  1
Form:       
---
Ingredient: Candesartan cilexetil
Brand name: Atacand
Strength:   4mg 
Pack size:  30
Form:       capsule
---
Ingredient: Danazol
Brand name: Azol
Strength:   100mg 
Pack size:  100
Form:       
---
Ingredient: Dexamethasone
Brand name: Dexmethsone
Strength:   0.5g 
Pack size:  1
Form:       tablet
---
```

---

Here'a **fixed and simplified version of your pure `bash` attempt**:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:][:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]])[[:blank:][:punct:]]+([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:][:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]])[[:blank:]]+([^[]+)\[([0-9]+)\][[:blank:]]*([[:alpha:]]*)$ ]]
  then    
    printf "Ingredient: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    printf "Brand name: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    read -r strength <<<"${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    printf "Strength: %s\n" "$strength"
    printf "Pack size: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    printf "Form: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
  fi  
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

- Instances of `([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:][:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]])` are used to capture the ingredient and the brand name; the expression captures a variable list of letter-only words separated by whitespace (containing at list a single, 2-letter word).
- The simplified regex avoids the `mcg` / `mg` / `g` parsing difficulty by matching everything after the brand name up to the following `[` (the start of the pack size) using `[^[]+`, however many spaces it contains; since that includes trailing whitespace, `read` is later used to trim that.

  - If you do need to match `mcg` / `mg` / `g` explicitly in order to rule out false positives:

    - Replace `[^[]+` with `([[:digit:].]+(mcg|mg|g)[/0-9a-zA-Z[:space:]]*)`
    - Replace `$BASH_REMATCH` index `5` with `6`, and `4` with `5`, because the above introduces a new capture group for technical reasons - see explanation below.
- Note how `[:blank:]` (matching a tab or a space) is used in lieu of `[:space:]`, because the latter also matches newlines, which are by definition not present here.

---

There are **various problems with your original attempt**, some of which have already been pointed out by [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) in comments on the question:

- `[mcg|mg|g]` should be `(mcg|mg|g)` or `(mc?)?g`, because `[mcg|mg|g]` is a [bracket expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05): in this case, a *set* of characters any one of which matches a *single* character, so that in you in effect match a *single* `m`, `c`, `|`, or `g` character.
- `[：space：]` uses *non-ASCII* [fullwidth colons](https://unicode-table.com/en/FF1A/), which Bash doesn't recognize as part of a character class.
- Not problems per se, but caveats and simplification opportunities:

  - You're mixing `[:alpha:]` and `a-zA-Z` which are only guaranteed to work the same in the ASCII range; to match foreign letter too, stick with `[:alpha:]`; conversely, `[:digit:]` could hypothetically match non-ASCII digits, so `[0-9]` may be the safer choice.
  - No need to escape `/` inside `[...]` in `bash`, because `/` is not a regex metacharacter and is also not used as the regex *delimiter* in `bash`.
  - `[\[]` and `[\]]` to represent literal `[` and `]` is unnecessarily complicated; use `\[` and `\]` instead.
- The main problem is that **you seem to have a misconception about how bracket expressions work**. For instance, `[[:digit:]+[mcg|mg|g][:space:][/0-9a-zA-Z[:space:]]*]` is an ill-constructed *single* bracket expression that should be multiple independent subexpressions:

  - `[[:digit:].]+` - a bracket expression to match a run of digits and/or `.` (to also match `0.5g`, for instance).
  - `(mcg|mg|g)` - a parenthesized subexpression (capture group) using alternation `|` to match any of the three tokens; note that using `(...)` in a `bash` regex *invariably* creates a capture group, even if you only need the parentheses for *precedence*, so you need to account for that when indexing into `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`.
  - `[/0-9a-zA-Z[:space:]]*` - another bracket expression that matches any (potentially empty) run of characters composed of `/`, decimal digits, ASCII letters, and whitespace characters.
  - Joining these subexpressions should then match a string such as `50mcg/1g 30 g`, which you can verify as follows:
    `[[ '50mcg/1g 30 g' =~ [[:digit:].]+(mcg|mg|g)[/0-9a-zA-Z[:space:]]* ]] && echo "MATCHED: >>>${BASH_REMATCH[0]}<<<"`
- There are **great online tools for visualizing and debugging regular expressions** that are also great teaching tools. One example is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com).

  - Note that these tools usually do not directly support the (often platform-specific) regex dialects found in `bash` and the various Unix utilities, but choosing `PCRE` as the dialect usually provides a *superset*.
    The caveat is that you need to know what subset your specific utility supports, otherwise you may end up with a regex that works in the online tester only.
  - A demonstration of how `[[:digit:].]+(mcg|mg|g)[\/0-9a-zA-Z[:space:]]*` matches `50mcg/1g 30 g` can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/n47vRN/1).
  - [Here](https://regex101.com/r/RzcQec/1) is the full regex from the fixed `bash` solution above tested against a full sample input line.